# Rails 3 - Expression-based Attribute in Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

How do I define a model attribute as an expression of another attribute?

Example:

```
Class Home < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :address, :phone_number
```

Now I want to be able to return an attribute like :area_code, which would be an sql expression like "substr(phone_number, 1,3)".

I also want to be able to use the expression / attribute in a group by query for a report.

This seems to perform the query, but does not return an object with named attributes, so how do I use it in a view?

Rails Console:

```
@ac = Home.group("substr(phone_number, 1,3)").count
=> #<OrderedHash {"307"=>3, "515"=>1}>
```

I also expected this to work, but not sure what kind of object it is returning:

```
@test = Home.select("substr(phone_number, 1,3) as area_code, count(*) as c").group("substr(phone_number, 1,3)")
=> [#<Home>, #<Home>]
```

To expand on the last example.  Here it is with Active Record logging turned on:

```
>Home.select("substr(phone_number, 1,3) as area_code, count(*) as c").group("substr(phone_number, 1,3)")

Output:
Home Load (0.3ms) SELECT substr(phone_number, 1,3) as area_code, count(*) as c FROM "homes" GROUP BY substr(phone_number, 1,3)
=> [#<Home>, #<Home>]
```

So it is executing the query I want, but giving me an unexpected data object.  Shouldn't I get something like this?

```
[ #<area_code: "307", c: 3>, #<area_code: "515", c: 1> ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot access to substr(...) because it is not an attribute of the initialized record object.

See : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html "selecting specific fields"

you can workaround this this way :

```
@test = Home.select("substr(phone_number, 1,3) as phone_number").group(:phone_number)
```

... but some might find it a bit hackish. Moreover, when you use select, the records will be read-only, so be careful.

if you need the count, just add .count at the end of the chain, but you will get a hash as you already had. But isn't that all you need ? what is your purpose ?

You can also use an area_code column that will be filled using callbacks on create and update, so you can index this column ; your query will run fast on read, though it will be slower on insertion.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but changing the group by to the alias had no effect on the output: @test = Home.select("substr(phone_number, 1,3) as area_code, count(*) as c").group("area_code") also returned "=> [#<Home>, #<Home>]", which I'm not sure what to do with.  I am not worried about writing to this this column, it is just an expression of the telephone number column. Also, I think worrying about indexes at this point is premature, I can't even get a working query.

Comment: i know, this column idea may be considered bad practice, but it is a frequent trick among rails developpers as far as i know. I also forgot that you can't access the substr because it is not part of the object's initialized attributes (see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html, "selecting specific fields"), so the column trick is a workaround for this. edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: That still doesn't work.  It completely drops the substr expression! per the ActiveRecord logging in the console: @test = Home.select("substr(phone_number, 1,3) as phone_number").group(:phone_number).count returns this: SQL (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, phone_number AS phone_number FROM "homes" group by phone_number => #<OrderedHash {"307"=>3, "515"=>1}>

Comment: your substr expression is not dropped. "307" should be the result of this expression. count() does not return an array of records but a hash, with result of substr as keys and the count of rows as values, so in this example you have three numbers in 307 area code. Your first query, the one that starts with @ac, does exactly the same thing... sorry but that's how calculations work in rails as far as i know (see the "calculations" part in the above link)